# https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo won't return email

Tags: php, laravel

I used this code before and I could receive the email but it doesn't work now .... why?

```
  $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=".$id,
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    try{
        $resp = json_decode($resp,true);
        if(empty($resp['error']))
            return $resp;
        else return null;
    }catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

`$id` is access_token/
i get name,picture,... but no email in array

Comment: What error do you get? What is the response? Normally you should see an error in your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two ways to solve this problem:

1. You should use this https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo to receive email and you should have `access_token`

Most programmers do not know the difference between `access_token` and `id_token`, and use `access_token` instead of `id_token` by mistake. the `access_token` is a string shorter than `id_token` and you should run this code for getting email:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlsJBxmiZkSmgMEUlhrtytyJEEI45uQTR8xmmrsZulz7kEOtyrtyytrycyPxCtg_TZ_hz3x5zI5fRlqgJ9ARCnQIEFZaO5o75ZbwicwFGFf_y7PZ8T",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Host: www.googleapis.com",
    "Postman-Token: 55ft6892-d0hc-43b0-af22-5eeced9155b5,58b4bd70-355c-4293-933c-30b1c0982b67",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;} else {echo $response;}
```

2. The mobile programmer receives an email retrieval value and the programmer does not need to call the above web service to get the email.

Finally I got some samples of `access_token` and `id_token`

`access_token`:

```
ya29.GlsJB84Op0099CWZzGrazU449yFBRX1IwA7kjQvUbISnzaP1tGrqzcH7Pdo-vynDF9GZ7L9El_cvMrX2UBedIcq00Ml4Id5wb1459qpxfB3IzHv7dFwTKyV28E5Y
```

`id_token`:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjJjM2ZhYzE2YjczZmM4NDhkNDI2ZDVhMjI1YWM4MmJjMWMwMmFlZmQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLm67b2dsZS5jb20iLCJhenAiOiI3MjI1NDU1MjAwODItdGNycTRhZzZpZjJwZmVsbXEwN2xoM2xlMm5uamljdHIuYXB67uy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiI3MjI1NDU1MjAwODI456NycTRhZzZpZjJwZmVsbX67N2xoM2xlMm5uamljdHIuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiIxMDg0MDMxNzUyMzc0NDg5OTI2OTQiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im5pZ2h0LmV4dGVybkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZ567dHJ1ZSwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IkIyVi1GenM5WjVHRm4wQjNEa0FUMXciLCJpYXQiOjE1NTc4Mjc3MTgsImV4cCI6MTU1NzgzMTgh7H0.S6VNWWcSzOqpNdOBBAY-tDmFJQu0ZTU5RSalYnsC0P4KuW6ts8f61PQT5X2a1DXjgV6vj3iu9T1Apj8RzvYezakruLt7doB9CI9vEr1hpOwCcQ3W_o8MkZWZUtU1i4heXM7k3uW9LQy5fa3mdY4pWX0YEa6x--eAnwvUHuJzrRIfn-boV4Rl1LkkCS7AKKMYpOC-_Gej5P9eu5xc7d-xtFr_Cv8ne5pnQKk-5Un9f3IV5SW9mi9AOJI_MdmKg1n-P495TAk5wrLUME5UOJTHgleh__TmfVZwpvvc-UVKtRObJhANubqqiTA_E5O1-TSdrj9yNNhldyxsL6Xb5MfsJQ`
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is from the docs:

> These fields are only included when the user has granted the "email" OAuth scopes to the application.

About 2 months ago google shutdown google+ api, if you wish to add your code where you acquire the token maybe we could help you a bit more.

Comment: my code retern--->`array (size=14)
  'iss' =>string '.' (length=27)
  'azp' =>string '.' (length=73)
  'aud' =>string '..' (length=73)
  'sub' => string '..' (length=21)
  'name' => string '..' (length=14)
  'picture' =>string '.' (length=121)
  'given_name' =>string '.' (length=6)
  'family_name' =>string '.' (length=7)
  'locale' =>string 'en' (length=2)
  'iat' =>string '..' (length=10)
  'exp' =>string '..' (length=10)
  'alg' =>string 'RS256' (length=5)
  'kid' =>string '..' (length=40)
  'typ' =>string 'JWT' (length=3)`
email is not in array @René-Höhle ,@tom-slabbaert